# jquery tooltip - click to open and click to close

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery popup working that shows on click. I need to make it hide again when the same selector is clicked. But at the moment it just flashes and reloads. I have set it up so it closes if you click anywhere that is not the selector but this is not really what I need.

Here is my code which works perfectly I just need to know how to make it hide when it is clicked again.

Basically what I think I need to know is how to keep track what selector has been clicked (there are multiple items that can be clicked on the same page all with the same class) so I can say if that is clicked again close it??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tooltip").hide();
        $("a.highScoreTooltip").click(function(){                                             
            var game = $(this).attr('title');
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var top = offset.top - 43;
            var left = offset.left + 155;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",       
                data: 'game=' + game,   
                url: "<?=$server_url?>leaderboard_popup.php", 
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { 
                    $("#tooltip").show();
                    $("#tooltip").html(html);
                    $("#tooltip")
                        .css("top",top + "px")
                        .css("left",left + "px")
                        .fadeIn("fast");
                }      
            }); 
        });
        jQuery(document).delegate(':not(#tooltip)', 'click', function(){
            $('#tooltip').hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: To keep track that selector has been clicked, You can add css class ([.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)) on click and remove ([.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)) on another click.

Comment: @marioosh Using a class for this seems a bit unnecessary, since it's only one property being changed (and there are more than enough jQuery functions to modify that particular property as it is) - also, if you did go for a class, why not use `.toggleClass()` and save yourself the hassle of testing it manually?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `.fadeIn("fast");` with `.toggle("fast")` in this section of code:

```
$("#tooltip")
    .css("top",top + "px")
    .css("left",left + "px")
    .fadeIn("fast");
```

May not give you the exact same animation (so may not be the answer you want), but it will handle the hiding/showing simply.

Comment: This works for when you click on the same selector, but now if i click on another selector (that shows the popup) if the popup is already showing it disappears instead of just moving to the next one and showing the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggle` like that:

```
$('#book').toggle('slow', function() {  // or toggle(showOrHide)
    $("a.highScoreTooltip").click(function(){                                              
            var game = $(this).attr('title'); 
            var offset = $(this).offset(); 
            var top = offset.top - 43; 
            var left = offset.left + 155; 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",        
                data: 'game=' + game,    
                url: "<?=$server_url?>leaderboard_popup.php",  
                cache: false, 
                success: function (html) {  
                    $("#tooltip").show(); 
                    $("#tooltip").html(html); 
                    $("#tooltip") 
                        .css("top",top + "px") 
                        .css("left",left + "px") 
                        .fadeIn("fast"); 
                }       
            });  
        }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should now use http://api.jquery.com/on/ instead of delegate apparently. You can just use the `.click()` method of course. All you need is to read in the current state of the object on click. If it is visible, then hide it, if not, then show it. You can achieve this with a global variable, or using the [visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

Comment: That depends on what version of jQuery you're using - the `.delegate()` function is the recommended method for those of us still using versions prior to 1.7.